# Having problems with make and opencv

Tags: centos, compiling, make

I'm trying to build opencv for my x86_64 Centos 6 operating system.

I think the problem is make is trying to use the 32 bit version of the bz2 library instead of the 64 bit version.

I get this error from make:

```
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dc1394_v2.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_v4l.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/lib/libbz2.so.1: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And I run cmake like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64 CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I have the library installed:

```
[root@localhost build]# ldconfig -p | grep libbz2
    libbz2.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libbz2.so.1
    libbz2.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/libbz2.so.1
```

What can I do to fix this problem? Thanks!

EDIT: I also have the directories /lib and /lib64 and in /lib64 I have libbz2.so.1 and libbz2.so.1.0.4

EDIT: And I'm following these instructions 
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing several other Q&A sites, I came up with the problem being that cmake is using the 32 bit library as if it were the 64 bit one.

I solved this on Fedora 22 by doing this:

1. remove your `CMakeCache.txt` file
2. run `cmake` to regenerate it

   ```
   cmake -D blah blah flags and values
   ```
3. Edit your `CMakeCache.txt` file and change this line

   ```
   //Path to a library.
   BZIP2_LIBRARIES:FILEPATH=/lib/libbz2.so.1
   ```

   to this

   ```
   //Path to a library.
   BZIP2_LIBRARIES:FILEPATH=/lib64/libbz2.so.1
   ```
4. Run `cmake` again (not sure if needed but just in case)
5. `make`

It then finished without errors